# Updater process ended with ERROR: 1

Tags: rooting, system-error

I just wanted to root my galaxy note 5 (sm-n920c (dual sim)). I used `SpaceX-Kernel-v0.1_N920CD(official).tar.md5`
 and `SpaceX-Kernel-v0.1_N920T(official).tar.md5`and `Noble_Kernel_Auto-Root_N920T_v0.1_Rebuid3.tar.md5` but they didn't work an gave me an error about `kernel is nor seandroid enforcing`  with red line above the startup page.

So I searched again and found this tutorial http://galaxynote5root.com/galaxy-note-5-root/how-to-root-galaxy-note-5-on-android-7-0-nougat-w-magisk/2/

everything was ok but in last step I got this error:

```
Updater process ended with ERROR: 1 
Error installing zip file'/sdcard/samsung-antiroot-removal-2.4.zip'
```

Also I have 6.4G free space on my phone!
What's the problem and how can I fix it?